# How to make FindMiniumum work with delayed function and NIntegrate

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization

I can plot my function `penalty[v]` just fine, but `FindMinimum` doesn't work, it just complains non-numerical values from `NIntegrate`.

```
gau[x_, v_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2*v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
data = {-5, -4, -3, 1, 2};
p[x_, v_] := Total[gau[x - data, v]]/Length[data];
penalty[v_] := Sum[Log[p[data[[i]], v]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]/Length[data]-NIntegrate[p[x, v]*Log[p[x, v]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Plot[penalty[v], {v, .01, 2}]
FindMinimum[penalty[v], {v, .25}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Side note: In my definition of `penalty`, I had to use `Sum` instead of `Mean` because when data is passed into `p[x_,v_]`, the data-data yields zeros instead of the cross terms.  Should I have coded that part differently too?)

Comment: Prevent symbolic evaluation using `NumericQ` i.e. define `penalty[v_?NumericQ] := restOfCode`. That should then work: [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VBmSf.png). See: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951

Comment: @MarcoB  Thank you, that works.  But nothing I've find in the docs helps me understand WHY that works.  As I understand the ?NumericQ suffix, it should just penalty[] not work if the v input wasn't numeric.  Is FindMinimum[] figuring out somehow that it needs to provide numeric inputs?  If you put a little bit of explanation into an Answer, I can Accept it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look at the FAQ I linked to? That should give you a head start.